# Beginner ruby flow control

Tags: ruby

Why am I getting false for the following code?

```
def test(s)
   tester = s.split(//)
   for char in tester
       if char != 1 or char != 0
          return false
       end  
   end
   return true
end 

puts test("11111000")
# => false
```

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is full of simple mistakes, assumptions probably brought over from other languages.

The `for` statement is hardly ever used. Instead you just iterate:

```
tester.each do |char|
  # ...
end
```

Secondly, strings and numbers are not equivalent and are never automatically converted. You must be explicit:

```
if (char == '1' or char == '0')
  # ...
end
```

Also you've got a logical error, where you're testing the wrong way. Those two conditions can never occur simultaneously since there's no character that will pass both tests. Anything that passes one automatically fails the other.

What you want instead:

```
unless (char == '1' or char == '0')
  # ...
end
```

In the end, though, if you're just testing to see if this string contains exclusively `1` or `0` then just use a simple regular expression:

```
def test(s)
  !!s.match(/\A[01]*\z/)
end
```

The `!!` double negative is to convert a potential regular expression match into a simple `true` or `false` value. That's all you need. `\A` and `\z` are used to define the "beginning" and "end" of the string respectively. If you're not familiar with regular expressions you should spend some time learning about them because they are extremely powerful and perform these tasks very simply.

Comment: `\Z` is a little tricky. `\z` would be a simpler counterpart of `\A`.

Answer (score 5):

It is because `char != 1 or char != 0` is always `true`. Whatever `char` is, it cannot be both `1` and `0` at the same time.

---

The following is only based on a guess regarding the purpose of the OP's code. If the purpose was to check if `s` includes nothing but `"1"` or `"0"`, then, I would do:

```
s !~ /[^01]/
```

Comment: Also `0` and `"0"` are not the same thing, so this code won't work in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to check that a string is made up of ONLY 1s and 0s, you can just do:

```
def test(s)
 s.scan(/[^0-1]/).length == 0
end 

puts test("11111000") # => true
puts test("1234") # => false
puts test("234") # => false
```

Comment: `puts test('1110001222334466') #=> true`!

Comment: Right. I am not really sure what the goal here was. I was just saying if the goal is to see whether the string CONTAINS 1s or 0s - what I posted would do.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is a string, so it will never equal either `1` or `0` - only `"1"` or `"0"`

This code will work:

```
def test(s)
   tester = s.split(//)
   for char in tester
       if char != '1' and char != '0'
          return false
       end  
   end
   return true
end 

puts test("11111000")
# => true
puts test("111110002")
# => false
```

a more succinct way to do the same will be

```
def test(s)
  s =~ /^[10]*$/
end
```

Comment: @sawa - of course it is relevant - OP code will always return false, even if he changes the _or_ to _and_

Comment: @sawa - The actual solution is a sum of this and your answer. :)

Comment: @sawa - I can say the same about your solution. I saw you already wrote that, and I opted not to repeat what you said. I added working code sample, containing a solution for both our observations (which you seemed to neglect to do).

Comment: @UriAgassi Okay, I agree with the first point. However, I didn't neglect to add a working sample. I didn't do so because that is not what the OP asked. Furthermore, it is impossible to give a working example since the OP has not stated what they are trying to do. Your "solution" is only based on a guess regarding what OP was trying to do.

Comment: @UriAgassi - LOL. Good one!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what this code is supposed to do, but you have used some constructions, that (even though they are available) would not be considered ruby-way:

- you have used `or` instead of `||` -- `or` is usually used for flow control notation, and has very low precedence
- you have used `for ... in ...` instead of iterator
- you are explicitly trying to return `true`/`false` while it can be done in cleaner way by using correct iterator.

Solution easier to read and understand would probably look more like that:

```
def test(s)
   s.split(//).any? { |char| char != 1 || char != 0 }
end
```

Please note that there are more problems with your code (comparing strings with numbers and using condition that is always true) pointed by others.

Comment: This will always return true

Comment: Just like original code, which probably has more problems than being written in non-ruby way.